# Replace string which contains curly braces

Tags: c#, .net, regex, asp.net-mvc, powershell

I have a declaration like

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

I want to replace `"The {0} must be at least {2} characters long."` with `"TestString"`.
Currently I am using Regex.Replace, but its not working. 
e.g.

```
string lno = "[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]";
pattern = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.";
string _name = Regex.Replace(lno, pattern, "TestString", RegexOptions.None);
```

Kindly help.

**Edit:**
I am parsing through each line of a class (using visual studio shell package), and trying to replace the mentioned string when found. I am storing the line number values into "lno". That's why I have initialized it like this here.
Its working good for normal striings like:

```
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
```

The issue is only when it parses the string with curly braces.

Thank You.

Comment: Well first off you need to escape those double quotes in the `lno` string with a \.  Then you can just use `string.Replace` instead or you need to also delimit the curly braces in your regular expression.

Comment: What are you attempting to do here? You cannot 'change' the message using code - its metadata and must be known at compile time.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Regex.Escape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx) method to escape the string:

```
string lno = "[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = \"The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.\", MinimumLength = 6)]";
string pattern = Regex.Escape("The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.");
string _name = Regex.Replace(lno, pattern, "TestString", RegexOptions.None);
```

From MSDN:

> Escapes a minimal set of characters (\, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^, $,., #, and white space) by replacing them with their escape codes. This instructs the regular expression engine to interpret these characters literally rather than as metacharacters.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use Regex for what you're trying to accomplish..

```
string lno = "[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = \"The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.\", MinimumLength = 6)]";
string pattern = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.";
string _name = lno.Replace(pattern, "TestString");
```

Answer (score 1):

You must be careful when defining your Regex Pattern. Characters like `{`, `}` or `.`, just to name a few in your expression, have a special meaning an need to be escaped.

```
var lno = "[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = \"The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.\", MinimumLength = 6)]";
var pattern = @"The \{0\} must be at least \{2\} characters long\."; // Don't forget the @
string _name = Regex.Replace(lno, pattern, "TestString", RegexOptions.None);
```

FIDDLE
https://dotnetfiddle.net/var2Fj

Comment: Thanx a lot. But how can I escape dynamically?

Comment: What is dynamic?